# How this += works here in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, operators

I'm learning loop in javascript, but in many examples I saw + =, I know it means a+= b ( a= a+b ) but I do not know what exactly mean here in this code,

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Why don't your run this code and see what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is writing out the inner html of the element with id = "demo". The loop iterates 10 times;

The html will look like this in each iteration:

1st iteration (appends `0<br>`)

```
<p id="demo">
0<br>
<p>
```

2nd iteration (appends `1<br>`)

```
<p id="demo">
0<br>
1<br>
<p>
```

and so on...

10th iteration (appends `9<br>`)

```
<p id="demo">
0<br>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
9<br>
<p>
```

So `+=` in this code is basically appending to the inner html i.e. keeping the previously written text intact and appending `i<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b` (there are some subtle differences, but we'll ignore them for now).

When one of the operands is a string, `+` results in concatenation. So `"ABC" + "DEF"` becomes `"ABCDEF"`. If only one of the operands is a string, the other is turned into a string first.

`innerHTML` gets or sets the HTML contents of an element, so `innerHTML += i` turns `i` into a string and then adds it to the HTML contents of the element.

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop 10 times

adding (i + a new line character) to the element demo i.e. inside the paragraph

each time the loop executes

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer in your question.

If

```
a += b
```

is the same as

```
a = a + b
```

then

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
```

is the same as

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + i + "<br>";
```

In other words, the value of `i` as a string (the loop counter variable) and `<br>` (an HTML line break) are being added on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
```

means here that the value of `i` will be appended to the `p` along with the previous values in `p` each time the loop executes or simply to make it more clear `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + "<br>"` is same as `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + i + "<br>";`.

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + i + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

If you will not do `+=` you will only get the last value

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `for` loop you get `innerHTML` of the element and adds `i` from loop and "border" (`<br>`), so you don't overwrite it fully, you are adding `i` and `<br>`, and as the result, you can see a list of numbers from 0 to 9, each starts with new row.

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + "<br>";` means that you take existing `innerHTML`, adds `i` and then adds `<br>`, and finally assign it to `innerHTML` of the element - very simple.